# Global namespace with mixed language solution

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, namespaces

I have a VB.NET project which has project references to another VB.NET project and a C# project. Each of the referenced assemblies defines a class with the same name, say `Class1`. I can't in either case access it without the namespace itentifier, i.e. `Dim c As Class1`, which would be ambiguous.

The compiler is forcing me to use

```vb
Dim c As Global.C#Namespace.Class1
```

but `Global` can be omitted for the VB.NET class

```vb
Dim c As VBNamespace.Class1
```

What function is the `Global` identifier serving in this case, and why only for the C# reference? And why is it unnecessary (actually `Global.VBNamespace.Class` *doesn't* compile) in the VB.NET case?

Comment: Does the root namespace of your VB project conflict with the C# namespace?  Does the C# namespace conflict with some System namespace?

Comment: A concrete example is important.  When you use `Globals` then the compiler ignores any `Imports` directives in your source code file.  You then have to type the *full* typename.  Which is RootNamespace.NamespaceName.Typename.  The RootNamespace name is set in Project + Properties, Application tab.

Comment: The RootNamespace of each project is different. Just using one `Globals` doesn't make the compiler ignore all `Imports` it seems. I made a new simple VB project and a C# and VB class library with different namespaces, and both defining Class1. Global is not required in this case (everything works as it should). I can't tell the difference between this and my solution.

Comment: What is the root namespace in your core VB project which references the other projects?

Comment: Core VB project: "Instruments", referenced projects: C#: "Companyname", VB: "Utilities". The conflicting classes are "Companyname.CompanynameSystem.Blade", "Utilities.Blade" respectively

Comment: Is there a dot before 'System'?  If you have a namespace within the referenced C# project called "System", then that's a problem and that's why you need the 'Global' keyword.

Comment: No, I thought you might ask that after I posted that. Should have clarified. It's CompanynameSystem one word.

Comment: Can you construct a test solution with the absolute minimum amount of code to reproduce the problem and then post the code for each project?  Also, include the 'root namespace' used for the VB projects only.  You should be able to reproduce this with just a few lines of code per project.

Comment: I figured it out. I had a class with the same name as c# namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a legacy class with the same name as the referenced C# namespace name. The compiler recognized that identifier to be the class instead of the namespace in the referenced assembly.

The important point is that the compiler was being confused by a namespace and a class sharing the same name.